# How to handle errors for AWS SNS Topic Subscription API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am calling the unsubscribe API of AWS using a subscription ARN as in the below code.

```java
UnsubscribeRequest request = new UnsubscribeRequest(subscriptionArn);
UnsubscribeResult result = sns.unsubscribe(request); 
System.out.println("UnsubscribeResult - " + result.getSdkResponseMetadata().toString());
System.out.println("UnsubscribeResult - " + result.getSdkHttpMetadata().getHttpStatusCode());
```

I am able to retrieve HTTP status code as 200 for successful API hit. For a few error cases, exception is thrown which is already taken care of. But I wanted to handle failure responses for all other scenarios. But I receive the same response metadata and HTTP status code for an invalid subscription ARN.

Thanks in Advance.